# Individual y-axis for each level in parallel coordinates plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally, parallel-coordinates

I'm trying to generate a parallel coordinates plot, where each variable has its own axis. For instance:

[image: Target plot]

So far, I've used the function `ggparcoord()` from the package `GGally`. However, as far as I can tell, it does not allow each variable to have its own axis as above.

Does anyone know how this may be done using `R`, preferably using `ggplot2`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any packages that can do this, but it's not too difficult to draw the axes yourself in ggplot.

Let's say we have a similar dataset to the one shown in your example plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

cars <- mtcars %>% 
          select(c(2:4, 6:7, 1)) %>%
          tibble::rownames_to_column("model") %>%
  as_tibble()

cars
#> # A tibble: 32 x 7
#>    model               cyl  disp    hp    wt  qsec   mpg
#>    <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Mazda RX4             6  160    110  2.62  16.5  21  
#>  2 Mazda RX4 Wag         6  160    110  2.88  17.0  21  
#>  3 Datsun 710            4  108     93  2.32  18.6  22.8
#>  4 Hornet 4 Drive        6  258    110  3.22  19.4  21.4
#>  5 Hornet Sportabout     8  360    175  3.44  17.0  18.7
#>  6 Valiant               6  225    105  3.46  20.2  18.1
#>  7 Duster 360            8  360    245  3.57  15.8  14.3
#>  8 Merc 240D             4  147.    62  3.19  20    24.4
#>  9 Merc 230              4  141.    95  3.15  22.9  22.8
#> 10 Merc 280              6  168.   123  3.44  18.3  19.2
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

We can calculate the axis breaks (and set the coordinates of the tick marks) using some simple arithmetic:

```
axis_df <- stack(cars[-1]) %>% 
             group_by(ind) %>% 
             summarize(breaks = pretty(values, n = 10),
                       yval = (breaks - min(breaks))/(max(values) - min(values))) %>%
             mutate(xmin = as.numeric(ind) - 0.05, 
                    xmax = as.numeric(ind),
                    x_text = as.numeric(ind) - 0.2)
```

And the co-ordinates for our actual axis lines like this:

```
axis_line_df <- axis_df %>% 
                  group_by(ind) %>%
                  summarize(min = min(yval), max = max(yval))
```

Now we need to reshape and normalize the original data:

```
lines_df <- cars[-1] %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), function(x) (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)))) %>%
   stack() %>%
   mutate(row = rep(cars$model, ncol(cars) - 1))
```

Finally, the plotting code would be something like:

```
ggplot(lines_df, aes(ind, values, group = row)) + 
  geom_line(color = "orange", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_segment(data = axis_line_df, aes(x = ind, xend = ind, y = min, yend = max),
               inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(data = axis_df, aes(x = xmin, xend = xmax, y = yval, yend = yval),
               inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = axis_df, aes(x = x_text, y = yval, label = breaks),
            inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = axis_line_df, aes(x = ind, y = 1.2, label = ind),
            size = 6, inherit.aes = FALSE, check_overlap = TRUE, hjust = 1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(50, 20, 50, 20))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again to @Allan Cameron for his excellent answer. I used his code to write a function that mimics `GGally::ggparcoord()`, but with individual y-axes. Here, the normalisation of the axis breaks and the data is done so that the heights of the axes are identical.

I also added an argument `truth`, which is an optional `data.frame` containing points to plot for each variable; in the context of my application, the lines correspond to parameter estimates, and the `truth` points are the true values we are trying to estimate.

Here is the function:

```
ggparcoord_ind_yaxis <- function(
  data,
  truth = NULL, 
  truthPointSize = 2, 
  columns = 1:ncol(data),
  groupColumn = NULL, 
  alphaLines = 1, 
  nbreaks = 4, 
  axis_font_size = 3
) {
  
  # select the variables to plot
  data_subset <- data %>% select(columns)
  
  # re-order truth to match columns
  col_names <- data_subset %>% names
  if (!is.null(truth)) {
    truth <- truth %>% select(col_names)
    data_subset <- data_subset %>% rbind(truth)
  } 
  
  # Calculate the axis breaks for each variable on the *original* scale.
  # Note that the breaks computed by pretty() are guaranteed to contain all of 
  # the data. We include truth in these breaks, just in case one of the true 
  # points falls outside the range of the data (can easily happen in the context
  # of comparing parameter estimates to the true values).
  breaks_df <- data_subset %>% 
    stack %>%           # convert to long format
    group_by(ind) %>%   # group by the plotting variables
    summarize(breaks = pretty(values, n = nbreaks))
  
  # Normalise the breaks to be between 0 and 1, and set the coordinates of the 
  # tick marks. Importantly, if we want the axis heights to be the same, the 
  # breaks need to be normalised to be between exactly 0 and 1. 
  axis_df <- breaks_df %>% 
    mutate(yval = (breaks - min(breaks))/(max(breaks) - min(breaks))) %>%
    mutate(xmin = as.numeric(ind) - 0.05, 
           xmax = as.numeric(ind),
           x_text = as.numeric(ind) - 0.2)
  
  # Calculate the co-ordinates for our axis lines:
  axis_line_df <- axis_df %>% 
    group_by(ind) %>%
    summarize(min = min(yval), max = max(yval))
  
  # Getting the minimum/maximum breaks on the original scale, to scale the 
  # data in the same manner that we scaled the breaks
  minmax_breaks <- breaks_df %>%
    summarize(min_break = min(breaks), max_break = max(breaks)) %>% 
    tibble::column_to_rownames(var = "ind")
  
  # Normalise the original data in the same way that the breaks were normalised.
  # This ensures that the scaling is correct. 
  # Do the same for the truth points, if they exist.
  lines_df <- data %>% select(columns) 
  for (col in col_names) {
    lines_df[, col] <- (lines_df[, col] - minmax_breaks[col, "min_break"]) / ( minmax_breaks[col, "max_break"] -  minmax_breaks[col, "min_break"])
    if (!is.null(truth)) {
      truth[, col] <- (truth[, col] - minmax_breaks[col, "min_break"]) / ( minmax_breaks[col, "max_break"] -  minmax_breaks[col, "min_break"])
    }
  }
  
  # Reshape original data (and truth):
  lines_df <- lines_df %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>% # need row information to group individual rows
    bind_cols(data[, groupColumn, drop = FALSE]) %>% # need groupColumn for colour aesthetic
    reshape2::melt(id.vars = c("row", groupColumn), 
                   # choose names that are consistent with stack() above:
                   value.name = "values", variable.name = "ind") 
  
  # Reshape truth, as above
  if (!is.null(truth)) {
    truth <- truth %>%
      mutate(row = row_number()) %>% # need row information to group individual rows
      reshape2::melt(id.vars = c("row"), 
                     # choose names that are consistent with stack():
                     value.name = "values", variable.name = "ind") 
  }
  
  # Now plot: 
  gg <- ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = lines_df %>% sample_n(nrow(.)), # permute rows to prevent one group dominating over another
              aes_string(x = "ind", y = "values", group = "row", colour = groupColumn), 
              alpha = alphaLines) +
    geom_segment(data = axis_line_df, aes(x = ind, xend = ind, y = min, yend = max),
                 inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_segment(data = axis_df, aes(x = xmin, xend = xmax, y = yval, yend = yval),
                 inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_text(data = axis_df, aes(x = x_text, y = yval, label = breaks),
              inherit.aes = FALSE, size = axis_font_size) 
  
  if (!is.null(truth)) {
    gg <- gg + geom_point(data = truth, aes(x = ind, y = values), 
                          inherit.aes = FALSE, colour = "red", size = truthPointSize)
  }
  
  gg <- gg + theme_bw() + 
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
          panel.border = element_blank(), 
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks =  element_blank(), 
          axis.text.y = element_blank()) 
  
  return(gg)
}
```

An example using the `iris` data set:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("tibble")

truth <- iris %>% select(4:1) %>% apply(2, median, simplify = FALSE) %>% data.frame

ggparcoord_ind_yaxis(iris, truth = truth, columns = 4:1, groupColumn = "Species", alphaLines = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: I like this example, but instead of coloring them according to the species, would anyone have any idea of how to make a gradient coloring according to their sepal.width?

Answer (score 1):

If someone finds the question on google like I did, the easy to use function from @MattSainsbury-Dale answer produces some warnings because of deprecated functions:

- Warning: Using an external vector in selections was deprecated in tidyselect 1.1.0
- Warning: Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.
- Warning: `aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0.

I fixed those as I might be using this on a Shiny app and thought I'd share it here.

```
#Original function by @MattSainsbury-Dale from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69694711/individual-y-axis-for-each-level-in-parallel-coordinates-plot 

library(reshape2)
ggparcoord_ind_yaxis <- function(
    data,
    truth = NULL, 
    truthPointSize = 2, 
    columns = 1:ncol(data),
    groupColumn = NULL, 
    alphaLines = 1, 
    nbreaks = 4, 
    axis_font_size = 3
) {
  
  # select the variables to plot
  data_subset <- data %>% select(all_of(columns))
  
  # re-order truth to match columns
  col_names <- data_subset %>% names
  if (!is.null(truth)) {
    truth <- truth %>% select(all_of(col_names))
    data_subset <- data_subset %>% rbind(truth)
  } 
  
  # Calculate the axis breaks for each variable on the *original* scale.
  # Note that the breaks computed by pretty() are guaranteed to contain all of 
  # the data. We include truth in these breaks, just in case one of the true 
  # points falls outside the range of the data (can easily happen in the context
  # of comparing parameter estimates to the true values).
  breaks_df <- data_subset %>% 
    stack %>%           # convert to long format
    group_by(ind) %>%   # group by the plotting variables
    reframe(breaks = pretty(values, n = nbreaks))
  
  # Normalise the breaks to be between 0 and 1, and set the coordinates of the 
  # tick marks. Importantly, if we want the axis heights to be the same, the 
  # breaks need to be normalised to be between exactly 0 and 1. 
  axis_df <- breaks_df %>% 
    group_by(ind) %>%
    mutate(yval = (breaks - min(breaks))/(max(breaks) - min(breaks))) %>%
    mutate(xmin = as.numeric(ind) - 0.05, 
           xmax = as.numeric(ind),
           x_text = as.numeric(ind) - 0.2)
  
  # Calculate the co-ordinates for our axis lines:
  axis_line_df <- axis_df %>% 
    group_by(ind) %>%
    summarize(min = min(yval), max = max(yval))
  
  # Getting the minimum/maximum breaks on the original scale, to scale the 
  # data in the same manner that we scaled the breaks
  minmax_breaks <- breaks_df %>%
    group_by(ind) %>%
    summarize(min_break = min(breaks), max_break = max(breaks)) %>% 
    tibble::column_to_rownames(var = "ind")
  
  # Normalise the original data in the same way that the breaks were normalised.
  # This ensures that the scaling is correct. 
  # Do the same for the truth points, if they exist.
  lines_df <- data %>% select(all_of(columns)) 
  for (col in col_names) {
    lines_df[, col] <- (lines_df[, col] - minmax_breaks[col, "min_break"]) / ( minmax_breaks[col, "max_break"] -  minmax_breaks[col, "min_break"])
    if (!is.null(truth)) {
      truth[, col] <- (truth[, col] - minmax_breaks[col, "min_break"]) / ( minmax_breaks[col, "max_break"] -  minmax_breaks[col, "min_break"])
    }
  }
  
  # Reshape original data (and truth):
  lines_df <- lines_df %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>% # need row information to group individual rows
    bind_cols(data[, groupColumn, drop = FALSE]) %>% # need groupColumn for colour aesthetic
    reshape2::melt(id.vars = c("row", groupColumn), 
                   # choose names that are consistent with stack() above:
                   value.name = "values", variable.name = "ind") 
  
  # Reshape truth, as above
  if (!is.null(truth)) {
    truth <- truth %>%
      mutate(row = row_number()) %>% # need row information to group individual rows
      reshape2::melt(id.vars = c("row"), 
                     # choose names that are consistent with stack():
                     value.name = "values", variable.name = "ind") 
  }
  
  # Now plot: 
  gg <- ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = lines_df %>% sample_n(nrow(.)), # permute rows to prevent one group dominating over another
              aes(x = ind, y = values, group = row, colour = get(groupColumn), linetype = get(groupColumn)), 
              alpha = alphaLines) +
    geom_segment(data = axis_line_df, aes(x = ind, xend = ind, y = min, yend = max),
                 inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_segment(data = axis_df, aes(x = xmin, xend = xmax, y = yval, yend = yval),
                 inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_text(data = axis_df, aes(x = x_text, y = yval, label = breaks),
              inherit.aes = FALSE, size = axis_font_size) 
  
  if (!is.null(truth)) {
    gg <- gg + geom_point(data = truth, aes(x = ind, y = values), 
                          inherit.aes = FALSE, colour = "black", size = truthPointSize)
  }
  
  gg <- gg + theme_bw() + 
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
          panel.border = element_blank(), 
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks =  element_blank(), 
          axis.text.y = element_blank()) 
  
  return(gg)
}
```