# How to create multiple y axis in ggplot2 (one for each variable)

Tags: r, ggplot2, parallel-coordinates

I would like to draw a plot similar to a Parallel Coordinates Plot for the descriptive statistics. I want to plot the mean and standard deviation for each variable stratified by sex.

[image]

Unfortunately, I couldnt figure out a way to create an own y axis for each variable.

It should look similar to this plot, but with the means and standard deviations instead of each row.

[image]

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69694711/individual-y-axis-for-each-level-in-parallel-coordinates-plot), they created the other plot, but I wasnt able to adjust it to my needs and my data, so that mean and standard deviation are depicted as in the plot above.

This is my data and code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

my_data <- data.frame(
  sex = c("m", "w", "m", "w", "m", "w"),
  age = c(25, 30, 22, 35, 28, 46),
  testosterone = c(450, 200, 400, 300, 500, 350),
  cognition = c(75, 80, 70, 85, 78, 90),
  estrogen = c(20, 40, 15, 50, 10, 45)
)

numeric_vars <- c("age", "testosterone", "cognition", "estrogen")

# Calculate means and standard deviations for each sex and each variable
df_means <- my_data %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(across(all_of(numeric_vars), mean, na.rm = TRUE))

df_sds <- my_data %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(across(all_of(numeric_vars), sd, na.rm = TRUE))

# Reshape data for ggplot
df_melted <- reshape2::melt(df_means, id.vars = 'sex')
df_sds_melted <- reshape2::melt(df_sds, id.vars = 'sex')

# Combine means and standard deviations
df_combined <- merge(df_melted, df_sds_melted, by = c('sex', 'variable'))
names(df_combined)[names(df_combined) == 'value.x'] <- 'mean'
names(df_combined)[names(df_combined) == 'value.y'] <- 'sd'

# Create a parallel coordinates plot without normalization
ggplot(df_combined, aes(x = variable, y = mean, group = sex, color = sex)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd, fill = sex), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("m" = "#007BC3", "w" = "#EA5451")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("m" = "#007BC3", "w" = "#EA5451")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: So do you still want a bunch of lines connecting everything? Then how do you want to draw the mean and standard deviation? Do you maybe just want a box plot or something instead? Do you really want a different scale for every variable? It's not clear what the desired output is here. Is there another plot you can point to that looks like what you are trying to create?

Comment: That's a type of plot with a specific name: a "parallel plot". There must be a ggplot-type version of it somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

The only "constants" in this are:

- `tick_ends` to define the offsets for the tick segments; and
- `hjust = 1.2`, providing a little distance between the segments and right-side of each text label.
- (I guess `pretty(n=8)`, for the approximate number of ticks to add) is also a magic-constant.)

I opted to set the levels of the `variable` factor to match the order of variables in your starting plot (which did not match your code), feel free to unset or change `levels=`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

long_data <- my_data %>%
  summarize(
    across(all_of(numeric_vars), list(mu = mean, sd = sd, min = min, max = max)),
    .by = sex
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-sex, names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)", names_to = c("variable", ".value")) %>%
  mutate(
    variable = factor(variable, levels = c("age", "testosterone", "cognition", "estrogen")),
    x = as.numeric(variable)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    min = min(min), max = max(max),
    mu_01 = scales::rescale(mu, from = c(min[1], max[1]), to = 0:1),
    sd_01 = sd / abs(min[1] - max[1]),
    .by = variable
  )
ticks <- summarize(long_data, .by = c(variable, x),
                   y = pretty(c(min, max), n = 8),
                   y_01 = scales::rescale(y, from = c(min[1], max[1]), to = 0:1))
tick_ends <- c(-0.05, 0)

ggplot(long_data, aes(x, mu_01, group = sex, color = sex)) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = x + tick_ends[1], xend = x + tick_ends[2], y = y_01, yend = y_01),
    data = ticks, inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_line(
    aes(x = x, y = y_01, group = variable),
    data = summarize(ticks, .by = variable, x = x[1] + tick_ends[2], y_01 = range(y_01)),
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = mu_01 - sd_01, ymax = mu_01 + sd_01, fill = sex), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = x + tick_ends[1], y = y_01, label = y),
    hjust = 1.2, data = ticks, inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = NULL,
    breaks = seq_along(levels(long_data$variable)),
    labels = levels(long_data$variable),
    limits = range(as.numeric(long_data$variable)) + c(-0.1, 0.1),
    minor_breaks = seq(1, 10, 1),
    position = "top"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, breaks = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("m" = "#007BC3", "w" = "#EA5451")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("m" = "#007BC3", "w" = "#EA5451")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

The use of `.by=` in the dplyr verbs requires `dplyr_1.1.0` or later; if you have an older version of dplyr, remove the `.by=c(..)` and add corresponding `group_by(..)` before the respective verb.

One possible (low-grade?) "risk" of scaling all variables to `[0,1]` based on their observed values is that it can hide or inflate that inferred relative magnitude/importance between the variables. Not sure there's an easy way to address this here.

---

### Extension

To make the inner axes align, I don't know if there's a better way than to control the rescaling in a way like this. Now using new data:

```r
my_data <- data.frame( sex = c("m", "w", "m", "w", "m", "w"), age = c(25, 30, 22, 35, 28, 46), testosterone = c(450, 5, 400, 10, 500, 15), cognition = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1), estrogen = c(20, 80, 15, 60, 10, 70), Var6 = c(1000, 900, 600, 800, 700, 500), Var7 = c(3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4), Var8 = c(20, 15, 30, 35, 25, 60), Var9 = c(0.6, 0.9, 1.4, 2.1, 1.2, 0.6), Var10 = c(200, 150, 300, 200, 130, 400), Var11 = c(900, 800, 450, 600, 650, 750), Var12 = c(30, 45, 60, 40, 30, 45) ) 
numeric_vars <- setdiff(names(my_data), "sex")
```

Using that and slightly-updated code:

```r
extend_rescale <- function(x, name = "variable") {
  p <- pretty(range(x))
  d <- diff(p)[1]
  p <- c(p[1], p[length(p)]) + d * c(-1, 1)
  out <- data.frame(
    x = scales::rescale(x, from = p, to = 0:1),
    step = d, min = p[1], max = p[2]
  )
  names(out)[1] <- name
  out
}

long_data <- my_data %>%
  summarize(
    across(all_of(numeric_vars), list(mu = mean, sd = sd, min = min, max = max)),
    .by = sex
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-sex, names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)", names_to = c("variable", ".value")) %>%
  mutate(
    variable = factor(variable), # set levels= if desired
    x = as.numeric(variable)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    extend_rescale(c(range(c(mu + sd, mu - sd)), mu), name = "mu_01")[-(1:2),],
    sd_01 = sd / abs(max[1] - min[1]),
    .by = variable)
ticks <- summarize(long_data, .by = c(variable, x),
                   y = seq(min[1], max[2], by = step[1]),
                   y_01 = scales::rescale(y, from = c(min[1], max[1]), to = 0:1))
tick_ends <- c(-0.05, 0)
```

(Same plot code.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: Would it also be possible for all y axes to start and end at the same height?

Comment: Yes, though it'll take a bit of work since the rescaling here is based on the range of observed values. To align the axes, we'll need to find the pretty numbers before rescaling. I'll get to it in a bit.

Comment: See my edit @Vivien, I think that should do it

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. Unfortunately the additional code does not work in my actual data as I have more variables with even more different scalings, like in the following example:

Comment: my_data <- data.frame(
  sex = c("m", "w", "m", "w", "m", "w"),
  age = c(25, 30, 22, 35, 28, 46),
  testosterone = c(450, 5, 400, 10, 500, 15),
  cognition = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1),
  estrogen = c(20, 80, 15, 60, 10, 70),
  Var6  = c(1000, 900, 600, 800, 700, 500),
  Var7 = c(3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4),
  Var8 = c(20, 15, 30, 35, 25, 60),
  Var9 = c(0.6, 0.9, 1.4, 2.1, 1.2, 0.6),
  Var10 = c(200, 150, 300, 200, 130, 400),
  Var11 = c(900, 800, 450, 600, 650, 750),
  Var12 = c(30, 45, 60, 40, 30, 45)
)

Comment: Got it, minor change (needed both `c(mu+sd, mu-sd)`, my bad), hope this works @Vivien